# What's wrong with this Kotlin FileFilter?

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I have the following FileFilter in my Kotlin Android app:

```
fileArray = fileDirectory.listFiles { file, filename ->
  file.length() > 0 && filename.matches(fileMatcherRegex)
}
```

It filters correctly on the filename matcher but it doesn't filter out files that have a length of 0. It I later iterate through fileArray and log the length of every file, I can sees lengths of 0.

Oddly, if I change the `file.length() > 0` to, say, `file.length() > 999999999999`, it filters out *all* the files, so the length() element of the filter is being tested. It's just not producing results I understand.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm still getting my head around Kotlin lambdas, so I'm guessing my error relates to that.

thanks in advance

John

Comment: I see you're declaring two parameters in the closure, but [the Java function appears only to accept 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html#accept(java.io.File))? Wonder if that's causing something funky to happen.

Comment: Oh thanks! That was it. I'm surprised it ran at all. This seems to work:
   fileArray = fileDirectory.listFiles { file ->
         file.length() > 0 && file.absolutePath.matches(fileMatcherRegex)
    }

Comment: Java defines both one and two parameter versions and they are completely different interfaces that the Lambda is implementing, see below...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method `listFiles` expects a lambda with two parameters which is based on the [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) from this method on the `FilenameFilter` interface:

```java
/**
 * Tests if a specified file should be included in a file list.
 *
 * @param   dir    the directory in which the file was found.
 * @param   name   the name of the file.
 * @return  <code>true</code> if and only if the name should be
 * included in the file list; <code>false</code> otherwise.
 */
boolean accept(File dir, String name);
```

The first parameter is the DIRECTORY containing the file, not the file itself.  Only the second parameter represents the file within the directory.  So your `file.length()` is checking `fileDirectory.length()` instead of the file's length.

In effect read your original code as:

```
val fileArray = fileDirectory.listFiles { directory, filename ->
  directory.length() > 0 && filename.matches(fileMatcherRegex)
}
```

And you can see now that it is incorrect logic.

If you use a single parameter to your lambda then you are specifying one based on the [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) from the `FileFilter` interface which is:

```java
/**
 * Tests whether or not the specified abstract pathname should be
 * included in a pathname list.
 *
 * @param  pathname  The abstract pathname to be tested
 * @return  <code>true</code> if and only if <code>pathname</code>
 *          should be included
 */
boolean accept(File pathname);
```

And this is the correct one, where you are asking questions about the file and not the containing directory.  Your code would then be:

```
val fileArray = fileDirectory.listFiles { file ->
  file.length() > 0 && file.name.matches(fileMatcherRegex) 
}
```

Comment: That makes sense of all the weirdness I was experiencing. Thanks for the very good explanation.